# Does the quantisation of energy apply to everything?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, discrete

Radiation is quantised according to Planck, so that's out of the question. However, I have seen many simplifications that claim Planck introduced quantised energy. Period. Has Planck really done that? Are all forms of energy, whether thermal, kinetic etc., quantised?

[Is every kind of energy quantised?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/504132/)
This question did not have satisfactory answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, as you indirectly reference: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/169218/297348 Arbitrarily small/continuous wavelength equals arbitrarily small/continuous photon energy...

Also, I think for macroscopic systems it hardly makes sense to ask that question.

Comment: that does not answer my question of "Are all forms of energy, whether thermal, kinetic etc., quantised?"

Comment: Giving an example of one form of energy that is not quantised clearly is an answer to your question.

Comment: You missed my point. Yes, radiation is not quantised per se, but its transfer most definitely is. In that sense, are the transfer of say, heat, and kinetic energy in discrete quanta of photons?

Comment: So, to get this right, does your question include: Does the increase of kinetic energy of a falling ball in a gravitational field (Newtonian) occur in a quantized manner, e.g. via some particles that are analogous to the photon?

Comment: pretty much yes.

Comment: Ok. I'm really no expert on this, but I believe there might be a "no"-answer to this question because there is no definitive theory of quantum gravity yet.

Comment: But the fact that it does not make sense to talk about quantum increases of energy for macroscopic/classical objects seems to be more important. (To me at least.)

Comment: thank you. I appreciate it